# GET http://localhost:7575/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, express

[image]
I just set up some endpoints for HTML pages and they work only they arent pulling any images or files.
I keep receiving the error message GET http://localhost:7575/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) for all my files no matter what file path I give them. Would anyone be able to take a look and help me with what I am doing wrong?
[![

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);


import {getData} from './server.js'
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static("public"));
// HTML Routes
app.use('/', router)

router.get('/', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../start.html"));
})
router.get('/war', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));
})
router.get('/score', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../finalScore.html"));
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>War</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> Game</div>
    <img src="./assets/images/cards/black_joker.png" height="300px" id="p1Card">
    <img src="./assets/images/cards/red_joker.png" height="300px" id="p2Card">

    <div type="text"  id="player1Results"></div>
    <div type="text"  id="player2Results"></div>

    <div type="text"  id="scoreTest"></div>
    <button onclick="start_round()">play me</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijPwO.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijPwO.png)

[image]

Comment: The issue is all about the context in which you are attempting to launch your web app, none of which is included in your question.  It's not really even possible to 100% tell what directory you're launching the package from.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [express guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) you should declare the static folder using the `express.static` function

The complete snippet is

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Comment: Still coming back with the error even though I added the above line of code.

Comment: @Alexis I didn't ask before replying, but have you started the express server? You should be doing so with
`app.listen(7575, () => { console.log('Example app listening on port 7575') })`
but I didn't see this code on your initial question

Comment: Ya its started. I keep refreshing per change as well. I tried your code above and even tried: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static('/public/assets/images/cards'));

Comment: Now playing close attention to your project workspace, I see several things wrong with it. The `server.js`, `api-routes.js` and especially `.env` all shouldn't be inside the public folder, they contain sensitive information, and shouldn't be available to the public. It be the best if you could move them to the root folder of your project, but some opt to leave them inside a folder called `src` or `lib`. Finally, could you edit your question with all code, and terminal output?

Comment: Here if this is easier this is the entire project https://github.com/AlexistehDevie/war-game-test/